# Mongo remove from nested object by value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo collection the consists of a document and a nested object describing what collections the document is in and when it was added. I would like to remove key-value pairs from a nested object based on a condition, e.g. is the value (a date) before 1-1-2016.

Example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581214940911ad3de98002db"),
    "collections" : {
        "c01" : ISODate("2016-10-27T15:52:04.512Z"),
        "c02" : ISODate("2015-11-21T16:06:06.546Z")
    }
}
```

needs to become

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581214940911ad3de98002db"),
    "collections" : {
        "c01" : ISODate("2016-10-27T15:52:04.512Z"),
    }
}
```

One alternative would be to change the schema to something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581214940911ad3de98002db"),
    "collections" : [
        {
            "id": "c01",
            "date": ISODate("2016-10-27T15:52:04.512Z")
        },
        {
            "id": "c02",
            "date" : ISODate("2015-11-21T16:06:06.546Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

in which case removing a document from a would be easy. I am a bit reluctant to do that because it would complicate some of the other queries I would like to support. Thanks!

Comment: You will do yourself a big favor if you change the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the second structure for your schema

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581214940911ad3de98002db"),
    "collections" : [
        {
            "id": "c01",
            "date": ISODate("2016-10-27T15:52:04.512Z")
        },
        {
            "id": "c02",
            "date" : ISODate("2015-11-21T16:06:06.546Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

then able to remove from `collections` like this

```
db.collectionName.update(
  { },// if you want can add query for specific Id {"_id" : requestId},
  { $pull: { collections: { date: {$lt: yourDate} } } }, // if need can convert iso date string like: new Date(yourDate).toISOString()
  { multi: true }
)
```